# Gradle run error : Java file not found

Tags: gradle, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a project in the Hybris running with **gradle.bat**
The code setup is working fine until clean and build, but when I run the **gradle.bat**. I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: *C:\{path}\gradle-4.6-bin.zip* (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a environment issue. Please confirm that the gradle is in the specified path itself.

**For better performance** :

**Step 1** : Place `gradle-4.6-bin.zip` in the `gradle/wrappe`r folder itself.

**Step 2** : Open the `gradle.properties` and replace the distribution URL with following, `distributionUrl=gradle-4.6-bin.zip`

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue with the ***gradle version.***

Check your version in the project structure and change gradle settings accordingly.